# Retrieve a list with angularFire and more than one child

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, angularfire2

I'm using angularFire to connect my page to my database. I want to display all the users stored in my firebase database in the form of a list on a page. The way I am storing these users is like this :

```
users
  |_date1
  |   |_hour1
  |       |_email:name
  |_date2
  |    |_hour2
  |        |_email:name
  |...
```

if I use the method below, I can only get one "subsection", not the other children...

```
this.fireDB.list('users').snapshotChanges().subscribe(res => {
        res.forEach(doc => {
        this.credentialsArray.push(doc.key, doc.payload.val());
    });
});
```

I need to put this in my `credentialsArray` with the `Credetial` model, so I can list it in my table:

```
this.credentialsArray.push(new Credential('name', 'email'));
```

And I want to get the time and date too.

How do I do it?

Comment: Your data model shows a `users`node and you call `this.fireDB.list('user')`, without s. I guess it is a typo in the first one.

Comment: @RenaudTarnec I edited the question, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can put data first in your object `Credential` before call in method:

```
this.fireDB.list('users').snapshotChanges().subscribe(res => {
        res.forEach(doc => {
        Credential cred = doc;

        this.credentialsArray.push(cred);
    });
});
```

Check if your object are ready for retrieve all data types.

Comment: But how would I differentiate the date, time, name and email?

Comment: cred.name or cred.getName, cred.email, cred.date, cred.time... I suppose that you are using Oriented-Object.